# Fail2ban apache-noscript jail violation rules?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, fail2ban

Which actions specifically are considered as violating apache noscript fail2ban module? I see that it correctly banned the ip that was looking for strange urls like "/admin" "/login" etc, but also blocked my ip and I checked the log for my ip and I didn't see any suspicious actions. So in one case it worked good in another it didn't.

Btw one of this line was considered as apache noscript violation. Why?

```
myip - - [05/Sep/2020:12:55:52 +0000] "GET /css/theme/jquery-ui.custom.css HTTP/1.1" 
myip - - [05/Sep/2020:12:55:52 +0000] "GET /img/icons/manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 
myip - - [05/Sep/2020:12:55:52 +0000] "GET /css/some.css HTTP/1.1" 
myip - - [05/Sep/2020:12:55:52 +0000] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 
myip - - [05/Sep/2020:12:55:52 +0000] "GET /ww.js.map HTTP/1.1" 
myip - - [05/Sep/2020:12:55:52 +0000] "GET /ww.js.map HTTP/1.1"
```

Btw, why are not attached the log files in the mail report? I edited in the fail2ban configuration the log to /access.log from /*access.log so hopefully it will help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Aha so the answer was not in the apache access.log but in the error.log:

[php7:error] [pid 7287] [client MYIP:42910] script '/var/www/html/error.php' not found or unable to stat

and reason is that in htaccess i have set the 404 page as /error.php I guess and it then triggers the apache-noscript jail as stated in the configuration file of this jail which is located in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-noscript.conf